# Prolog sublist Relation

Tags: list, prolog, sublist, difference-lists

I'm reading Ivan Bratko's Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence book and I have no experience with Prolog before. In book a sublist relation for a list is formulated as:

```
S is a sublist of L if:
1) L can be decomposed into two lists, L1 and L2, and
2) L2 can be decomposed into two lists, S and some L3.
```

And relation is given as:

```
sublist(S, L) :-
    conc(L1, L2, L),
    conc(S, L3, L2).

conc([], L, L).
conc([X|L1], L2, [X|L3]) :-
    conc(L1, L2, L3).
```

It seems odd to me why we don't just decompose list into two lists and check whether one of the lists matches with S?

Comment: `conc(L1, L2, L)` _is_ decomposing the list into two lists; your suggested implementation would therefore look like `sublist(S, L) :- conc(_, S, L) ; conc(S, _, L).` If you look at the output of that implementation with `sublist(S, [1,2,3,4])`, you'll notice `[2,3]` is never generated, but instead you get all sublists starting with 1 and also all sublists ending with 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get the impression that you're very close when you write:

> It seems odd to me why we don't just decompose list into **two** lists and check whether one of the lists matches with S?

Just decompose the list `L` into **three** lists and you're there:

- `L1` is a list that precedes the sublist ("prefix"),
- `S` is the sublist itself, and
- `L3` is a list that follows the sublist ("suffix").

As `conc/3` can only concatenate (or decompose) two lists—not three—a conjunction of *two* `conc/3` goals is required.

`conc(L1,L2,L), conc(S,L3,L2)` expresses above relation.

Comment: I understand. Why you're using /3 or /* suffix?

Comment: Think about expressing the sum of 3 numbers with a binary operator. Just like addition, concatenation is *associative*. So we can write `L1 + S + L3 = L` as `(L1 + S) + L3 = L` or (like above) as `L1 + (S + L3) = L`.

Comment: @TolgaKarahan `/*` is an indicator of arity: `length/2` is a binary predicate (with two arguments), `append/3` is ternary (with three arguments). Same name can be used to define predicates with different arities.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This should help; the key word/concept is `difference list`.

[image]

From "Prolog Techniques" by [Attila Csenki](https://www.bradford.ac.uk/ei/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/staff-profiles/profile/?u=acsenki), Chapter 2 (Free [PDF](https://library.ku.ac.ke/wp-content/downloads/2011/08/Bookboon/IT,Programming%20and%20Web/prolog-techniques-applications-of-prolog.pdf) with embedded ads)

A little latter in the book is this image

[image]

---

Second part of book is actually a separate book,

"Applications of Prolog" by [Attila Csenki](https://www.bradford.ac.uk/ei/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/staff-profiles/profile/?u=acsenki) (Free [PDF](https://library.ku.ac.ke/wp-content/downloads/2011/08/Bookboon/IT,Programming%20and%20Web/applications-of-prolog.pdf) with embedded ads)

Comment: Thank you. I'll examine this.

Comment: Technically, although one term is *difference list*, `[a,b,c|X]-X` doesn't really mean `[a,b,c|X]` minus `X` as illustrated. The `-X` part of the term gives access to the tail of the list with an explicit variable outside of the list. Thus, you might have `[a,b,c|X]-X` unified at some point with `L-T`. In that case, `T` will be the tail of `L`. The `[a,b,c|X]-X` term actually subsumes the whole list, `[a,b,c|X]`. The `X` is often referred to as a *hole*. See [Open Lists and Difference Lists](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pbrna/prologbook/node180.html).

Comment: While [tag:difference-lists] are a valuable concept, this question actually does not *require* difference lists. So a simpler answer might be more helpful.

Comment: Interesting side note: This is the first book in years that I could not find at [WolrdCat](https://www.worldcat.org/) by either title, author or ISBN. ISBN: `978-87-7681-476-2`

Answer (score 2):

For comparison purposes, the definition of the `sublist/2` predicate used in the Logtalk library is:

```
sublist(List, List).
sublist(Sublist, [Head| Tail]) :-
    sublist(Tail, Head, Sublist).

sublist(Sublist, _, Sublist).
sublist([Head| Tail], _, Sublist) :-
    sublist(Tail, Head, Sublist).
sublist([Head| Tail], Element, [Element| Sublist]) :-
    sublist(Tail, Head, Sublist).
```

IIRC, this is a common definition.Some sample calls could be:

```
?- list::sublist(Sublist, [1,2,3]).
Sublist = [1, 2, 3] ;
Sublist = [2, 3] ;
Sublist = [3] ;
Sublist = [] ;
Sublist = [2] ;
Sublist = [1, 3] ;
Sublist = [1] ;
Sublist = [1, 2].

?- list::sublist([1,2], List).
List = [1, 2] ;
List = [_1376, 1, 2] ;
List = [_1376, _1382, 1, 2] ;
List = [_1376, _1382, _1388, 1, 2] ;
...

?- list::sublist(Sublist, List).
Sublist = List ;
List = [_1172|Sublist] ;
List = [_1172, _1178|Sublist] ;
List = [_1172, _1178, _1184|Sublist] .
...
```

**Update**

Noticed that the definition in the question and the one in my answer don't have the same semantics. The definition in the question implies consecutive elements. E.g.

```
?- sublist(Sublist, [1,2,3]).
Sublist = [] ;
Sublist = [1] ;
Sublist = [1, 2] ;
Sublist = [1, 2, 3] ;
Sublist = [] ;
Sublist = [2] ;
Sublist = [2, 3] ;
Sublist = [] ;
Sublist = [3] ;
Sublist = [] ;
false.
```

One issue in this definition is that the empty list solution is generated multiple times.